# Proper way to customize apache behavior

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4

I want to do some customization to my apache server but am not very experienced in the field.

First thing I want to figure out is how to add custom configuration so that it wont break if an upgrade of apache occurs or anything. I created an `apache.conf` file in my `home` directory and I plan on including it in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, is that a good idea?

After I figure out how to include my custom configuration, I want to make apache log (access and error) into files based on subdomain, for example if a request is coming for `site.domain.com` it has to be logged in `/var/log/apache2/site.domain.com-access.log`.

I could not find anything on that but I'm imagining something like

```
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/${HTTP_HOST}-access.log combined
```

But when I do that I see the literal `${HTTP_HOST]-access.log` file in the directory.

Also I want to avoid logging requests from two IPs or ending in `breaker=\d+` (regex). For the purpose I suppose I must use the `If` and `SetEnv` clauses but I have no idea how to do that and combine them as well.

```
<If "${REMOTE_ADDR} 127.0.0.1 || ${REMOTE_ADDR} 192.168.1.1 || ${REQUEST_URI} breaker=\d+$">
  SetEnv nolog
</If>

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/${HTTP_HOST}-access.log combined env=!nolog
```

I can't find my ways through apache documentation, please help!

Comment: You could start by reviewing Ubuntu's specific apache config layout, as it should say on the first start page when you installed your server. AFAIR ubuntu has config split in files found in `config-available` subdir and you enable them by using `sudo a2ensite <site>` and so on. Your desired configuration with separate log files by subdomain accessed could be achieved by means of virtualhosts, where you can specify separate log files for every one of them. I do just that, although on Win platform.

Comment: @Kitet that is how I have it set up now but as the number of sub-domains increases it makes no sense to hard-code the path in every virtual host, I could just have it defined as the host name + `-access.log`, it would simplify my virtual host config files.